# fatal error: sys/dpli_common.h no such file

Tags: c

Hi i try to compile this program:

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
   #include <sys/dlpi_ether.h>
   #include <sys/dlpi_common.h>
   #include <stropts.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int fd, status;
    struct strioctl strcmd;
    unsigned char addr[6];
            fd = open(argv[1],0,0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("enaddr: open");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcmd.ic_cmd = DLIOCGENADDR;
    strcmd.ic_timout = 0;
    strcmd.ic_len = sizeof(addr);
    strcmd.ic_dp = addr;

    status = ioctl(fd,I_STR,&strcmd);
    if (status == -1) {
        perror("enaddr: ioctl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%02.2x:%02.2x:%02.2x:%02.2x:%02.2x:%02.2x\n",addr[0],addr[1],addr[2],addr[3],addr[4],addr[5]);
}
```

And the terminal returns this fatal error:

prova.c:3:30: fatal error: sys/dlpi_common.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Why? Where is this library?

Comment: Are you sure the `dlpi` component is installed on your system?

Answer (score 0):

It *should* be in the same place as `dlpi_ether.h`, which your system is not complaining about.

It's not really a C question insomuch as it will very much depend on the environment you're working in rather than C itself. All we can say is that you don't have that header file.

If you're under a UNIX like OS, you can go looking for it with something like:

```
find /usr/include -name 'dlpi*.h'
```

---

It appears that those header files may well not be in Linux at all, based on [this link](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/solaris_linux_app.html) from Oracle:

> The code to read raw Ethernet is quite different between the Solaris OS and Linux (libpcap can also be used to examine the differences with other systems, such as FreeBSD, HP-UX, and AIX).
>
> The applicable code in libpcap is at pcap-linux.c and pcap-dlpi.c. The DLPI code is used for Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, and other operating systems. Linux provides a mechanism for reading raw socket packets via the standard socket calls. The Solaris OS uses the getmsg(2) and putmsg(2) calls to receive and send DLPI packets.

Comment: i  have mint 12 and i don't have this!